# how to manage tabindex in joomla chronoforms

Tags: joomla1.5

hi i am using joomla for my one site can u help me set to default tab in chronoform.
i put this code in this but still it not set cursor in text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building your form using the form wizard, you will need to go back in to the form code and manually add the tabindex yourself. Be warned that editing the form code will cause issues if you try to use the wizard to go in and edit the form again. Any changes you make will be lost when you use the wizard and will have to be reapplied when you are done.

Comment: Do you have a link? Also, do you mean having the cursor in the first box when the page loads or the order that the fields are in when you use tab to navigate to the next field?